# Laravel doesn't accept $primaryKey

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Laravel 4 is not accepting my definition of `$primaryKey`

My Model looks like

```
class Email extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'emails';
    protected $primaryKey = 'email';
}
```

Controller looks like:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = Input::get('name');

$email = new Email();
$email->email = Input::get('email');

$user->emails()->save($email);
$user->save();
```

Database tells me

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'field list' 
>   (SQL: insert into `emails` (`email`, `id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`)
>   values (myemail@me.com, , 2014-10-04 11:12:25, 2014-10-04 11:12:25))

Database schema

```
create table `emails` (
    `email` varchar(255),
    `confirmed` char(1) not null default 'N',
    `user_id` bigint(20),
    `created_at` timestamp not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `updated_at` timestamp not null default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    primary key (`email`)
);
```

Relations

```
class Email extends Eloquent {
    ...
    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }
    ...
}

class User extends Eloquent {
    ...
    public function emails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Email', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
    ...
}
```

How can I get rid of the id column in the insert query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first change the order of saving to:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = Input::get('name');
$user->save();

$email = new Email();
$email->email = Input::get('email');
$user->emails()->save($email);
```

**EDIT**

The problem is your relation:

```
return $this->hasMany('Email', 'id', 'user_id');
```

it should be:

```
return $this->hasMany('Email', 'user_id', 'id');
```

assuming in `User` table you have column `id`

Comment: @PaDdy Edit your post and show how you have defined your relations